# how to structure Landing page in yeoman fullstack generator

Tags: angularjs, structure, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I'm going to add a landing page for my project, so I have created new Layout and put the whole html of the landing page. however I want to add the js and css

In general in the yeoman project the css and js is loaded in the index.html that calls the layout.

I don't want to load all the scripts that is used inside the project and load them in the landing page.

where can I put the css and js files ?